# Create Service Area free GIS Tools

Tags: open-source-gis, network-analyst

Is there a way to to something like `ArcGIS` provides with the `Network Analyst` with open source GIS tools?

What I am exactly looking for is:
I am having a roadnetwork and in this roadnetwork I have several points. I want to check if any of these points is further apart from each other than a certain threshold (lets say 1km).

Is there a way to do that with freely available GIS?

I am aware of this
https://anitagraser.com/2011/05/13/catchment-areas-with-pgrouting-driving_distance/
But that just gives me the distance of one point.

Comment: Spatialite virtual network perhaps https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=VirtualNetwork+reloaded

Comment: @user30184 that is basically the same as in the anitagraser.com example? Its just calculating from one node!

Comment: Probably it is. Could you add some links or images to what you want to achieve for those who have never seen Network Analyst in action?

Comment: As I understood your question, you basically need to calculate the distance between all points to all points and then list those pairs that have a distance > threshold? In this case, you could use Python networkx package that can create a graph from shapefile and solve routes between points, but you will need some Python. Otherwise, pgrouting between every pair and compare the distances.

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov yes. What I basically need is to calculate the service Area for each point in a network(based on distance in time/metres/etc). Ideally would be to be able to visualize it like so https://pro.arcgis.com/de/pro-app/help/analysis/networks/GUID-0166E6A5-CDEC-4A03-A022-F4A6EB7F9EAD-web.png. In ArcGIS this are a few clicks and I wonder if there is a good free solution.

Comment: @user30184 See here: https://pro.arcgis.com/de/pro-app/help/analysis/networks/GUID-0166E6A5-CDEC-4A03-A022-F4A6EB7F9EAD-web.png

Comment: In the Spatialite network document new tables are created for visualization `CREATE TABLE min_15 AS
SELECT NodeTo AS NodeId, Geometry
FROM roads_net
WHERE NodeFrom = 681429057 AND Cost <= 900;` Create tables with Cost<=1000 meters for each of your points and collect the individual tables into map project for visualization.

Comment: @Stophface, I think you misinterpret your needs. You don't need to generate drive-time polygons for every point. You only need to calculate the route between every pair of points. Again, this can be easily done with networkx Python package. Knowing the pair travel distance, you take only those you need.